# Google Maps JavaScript V3 Api place div on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I find it strange that no one needed this before (I assume this, because I didn't find anything about this subject ...).

Anyways, I want to put a div instead of a marker on a map. Is this possible? I did that before in Actionscript like this: `markerOptions.icon = new customDisplayObject();` You were able to give some options to the marker and define a DisplayObject to it.

So what I want now is that I can put:

```
<div>
    <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```

instead of a marker on the map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, you may create a custom overlay which may contain HTML-markup.

Start your research at <del>[**OverlayView**](http://google.maps.OverlayView)</del>

edit: replaced old link: [**Google Developers: Overlay**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

[**Sample that draws a custom image on a map**](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html)