# in Google maps, How can i specify multiple click areas to a custom marker image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Lets say i have a maps marker with a custom circular image  with 2 halves, one color black and another colored white.

Is it possible to specify a certain action when the left half is clicked and a different action when the right half is clicked?

Comment: Could you give an example or be more specific, and might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible but you would have to essentially overlay your marker with a div on one side and a div on the other. (essentially halving your marker)

[Google Maps JavaScript V3 Api place div on marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433058/google-maps-javascript-v3-api-place-div-on-marker)

Then add an onclick event to each div the left and right divs, and perform your click logic event/routine.

All of that being said, I would think that what your attempting to accomplish may be easier to do with some voting buttons in the infowindow.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/0Wc_wAQVHGk